# I have a YMA Visa - will Germany let me into the country despite COVID-19?

Tags: visas, air-travel, germany, canadian-citizens, covid-19

I am Canadian. Since I applied for the visa shortly before the situation got serious, I now have a valid work and travel visa for Germany, but I am afraid they will turn me away at the border/airport.. any thoughts on that matter ?

Comment: Isn’t EU closed? Why do you think you would be allowed?

Comment: Instead of asking on the internet, wouldn't it make more sense to take it up with Canadian embassy in Germany? Or is it on lockdown as well? As far as I know, most official places should be reachable via phone.

Comment: I would say the German embassy in Canada, but only contact them if you have an urgent reason to travel.

Comment: Ask the German customs officer at the border if you can come in. He will know that.

Comment: Should this be on [Expats.SE]?

Comment: I don't think this is at all opinion based, despite what the banner would have you believe.  In fact I (and one other, perhaps @gerrit) voted to close as off-topic in favor of [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Yes, this should be on Expatriates and not closed. It is specific to the present ban for a **long-term** visa holder which under certain conditions is not effected by that ban.

Answer (score 34):

**You will almost certainly be refused boarding by the airline or be turned away at the border by immigration**.

Germany has enacted an [entry ban on all non-citizens](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/einreiseundaufenthalt/coronavirus), with the only exceptions being for certain travellers transiting to get to their home country or travellers seeking entry into Germany for urgent reasons.

**Unless you have an urgent reason to enter Germany, your work visa will not secure your entry at this point in time.**

Comment: The article you are linking to seem incomplete. Residents of Germany are also allowed to enter (and not just citizens). It is not clear from the new regulations how persons who have been granted the right to reside, but not yet taken up residency are to be treated.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo as I note in the comments to the other answer, a YMA visa isn’t necessarily a residency visa.

Comment: You won't get a D visa unless you plan to stay in Germany for more than 3 months and if you stay in Germany more than 3 months, you are counted as a resident. The important objection was however that you summarize the page you are linking to with 'entry ban on all non-citizens'. I realize that the page you are linking to claims so, but it contradicts most other information. Citizens *and residents* are allowed to enter Germany (among several other groups).

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo its quite the other way around - the German Interior Ministry is running a campaign with great effort to bring "stranded" Germans home from other countries they visited for various reasons. Those people are then inspected, and asked for self quarantine depending on source location (risky regions, number of Covid-19 cases in said country or narrowed down to number of cases in the specific region)

Comment: @eagle275 I have no idea what is "the other way around". Did I write anything contradicting what you are saying here?

Comment: And rightfully so....

Answer (score 23):

A **Youth Mobility Visa** is a D-Visa (i.e. longer-term visa) and therefore **does not** generally fall under the ban

- as opposed to a C-Visa which does

From: [Federal Minister Seehofer ordered **extensive restrictions on entry at Germany’s external Schengen borders** in order to contain the spread of the coronavirus](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/pressemitteilungen/DE/2020/03/corona-reisebeschraenkungen.html:https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/pressemitteilungen/DE/2020/03/corona-reisebeschraenkungen.html):

> The same applies [extensive restrictions on entry] to third-country nationals with a longer-term right of residence (residence title **or longer-term visa**) in an EU member state or one of the countries mentioned above.
>   ...
>   But travel **for tourist purposes** by third-country nationals with a Schengen visa is no longer permitted. Whether to continue operating cross-border public transport (local and regional) is a matter for the relevant federal states to decide.

Check the entry on the sticker **Type of Visa**

- when **D**, an Airline should allow you to board

An **urgent reason** or **essential travel** is, however, needed to enter the country, which will be determined at the port of entry.

Since the main purpose of the **Youth Mobility Visa** is:

> to complement their post-secondary education, acquire hands-on work experience, and improve their knowledge of the other country’s language, culture and society.

this will likely be considered **non-essential** travel until (at least) May.

If your visa was issued before the ban was in place, you should contact the issuing consulate and seek (in writing) confirmation that the purpose is considered essential.

Without such a confirmation you should reconsider traveling at all.

---

> **[I have been issued a national visa, but I am not able to leave Canada as planned due to COVID-19. Can the visa be re-issued with an updated travel date?](https://canada.diplo.de/ca-en/consular-services/visa/yma?openAccordionId=item-2319036-1-panel)**
>   Your visa has been issued for a certain period of time (90+ days). If you are not able to leave before the expiry date of your visa, you must submit a new visa application. A processing fee will be charged. We recommend booking an appointment with the local aliens authority in Germany prior to leaving Canada. This way, your residence permit can be issued shortly upon arrival. Please note that the processing fee of your original visa application cannot be reimbursed.

---

> **[What are urgent reasons for crossing the border?](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/coronavirus-faqs.html#doc13797140bodyText3)**
>   The decision of whether a personal journey is an urgent ground for crossing the border is at the discretion of the border official. Federal Police officers are experienced in this type of decision-making, which is part and parcel of the role of border police.

---

**Sources**:

- [Work and Travel in Germany with the Youth Mobility Visa - Federal Foreign Office](https://canada.diplo.de/ca-en/consular-services/visa/yma?openAccordionId=item-2319036-1-panel)

  - [Coronavirus and entry restrictions: 4 things travelers to Germany need to know - Federal Foreign Office](https://canada.diplo.de/ca-en/coronavirus/2317268)
  - [BMI - Civil Protection - Coronavirus: Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/coronavirus-faqs.html#doc13797140bodyText3)

    - [BMI - Bevölkerungsschutz - Coronavirus: Fragen und Antworten](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/DE/themen/bevoelkerungsschutz/coronavirus/coronavirus-faqs.html#doc13738352bodyText3) (German version)
  - [BMI - Press - Federal Minister of the Interior Horst Seehofer orders far-reaching travel restrictions for international air and sea traffic](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/pressemitteilungen/EN/2020/03/far-reaching-travel-restrictions.html)

    - [BMI - Presse - Bundesinnenminister Seehofer ordnet weitreichende Reisebeschränkungen im internationalen Luft- und Seeverkehr an](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/pressemitteilungen/DE/2020/03/corona-reisebeschraenkungen.html:https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/pressemitteilungen/DE/2020/03/corona-reisebeschraenkungen.html) (German version)

Comment: A "D visa ... does not generally fall under the ban": this is incorrect.  Those with residence permits may enter, but a D visa is not a residence permit.

Comment: @phoog From what I can find of official information, *residents* can enter. If you have a type D visa, make use of it and stay in Germany, you are counted as a resident. Germany actually make use of the D visa as a de facto residence permit for a planned residency of less than one year. In this case, I would rather doubt that entry is possible since the right to reside has only been granted, while the residency itself has not yet started.

Comment: @phoog A D-Visa is  a **longer-term visa** and the term is explicitly used in the ban (residence permit or longer-term visa).  The source with this text in English has been added.

Comment: @phoog from my research, it looks like a Youth Mobility Visa is both not a residency visa and also can trivially become one after you arrive.  It looks like the German system is quite complicated...

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo from my research, it depends on how the application was made - you may not get residency with the YMA visa, you may have to apply for it after arrival. https://www.freecandie.com/applying-for-the-germany-youth-mobility-visa/ (note the residency mainly talked about there is the requirement to register as resident, not a residency visa - that’s the visa extension being talked about)

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbo That is correct. It can also be used for other purposes allowing a longer stay that 90 days (which is the maximum of  C-Visa).

Comment: See also https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/305265/en/

Comment: @Moo That would be the registration at the registry office (Meldebehörde) which is a general requirement for all persons staying longer that 3 months.

Comment: @Moo If someone wishes to stay for 9 months only a D-Visa will be issued (no residence permit needed). If someone wishes to take up residence, the Consulate (which cannot issue a residence permit) will issue a D-Visa, after the OK from the local authority that will later issue the residence permit after arrival.

Comment: @MarkJohnson thank you for adding that source.  I have removed my downvote.  Still, I hesitate to upvote because I suspect that in this case the traveler is likely to be denied entry in line with the analysis at the end of this answer.  The answer would be clearer if that were mentioned closer to the beginning.

Comment: @phoog This is a complicated matter. 1) Airline: C-Visa **no** ; D-Visa **maybe** 2) Port of entry: The reason why this D-Visa may not be accepted. It would seem to me the correct order.

Comment: @MarkJohnson your first quote ("The same applies to...") appears out of context. That sentence appears to refer to the section preceding it which is *not* about entry into Germany, but about _transiting_ through Germany in order to reach your country of residence. The restriction appears to apply to all Germans, regardless of nationality or visa type. There is no language specifically mentioning foreign residents of Germany, although they will probably be considered having an "important reason" to enter.

Comment: @averell The main context (as I read it and reflected in the answers in the FAQ's) in the first paragraph is **extensive restrictions on entry**. Paragraphs 2-5 refer to this main point. In the state based bans (which apply once the border has been crossed), *returning to your place of residence* is considered an 'important reason' and apply to all residents.

Comment: @MarkJohnson There is [additional guidance available](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/coronavirus-faqs.html#doc13797140bodyText3). This also appears quite clear that only German citizens have a _right_ to enter. EU and non-EU citizens can be turned away unless they have an "important reason" (which is totally at the discretion of the border official). It is likely that returning residents will have an "important reason" - but this is not stated specifically. What _is_ stated is that people may pass _through_ Germany to their country of residence.

Comment: @averell The English text differs from the German text: [BMI - Alle Meldungen - Wichtige Hinweise zu vorübergehenden Grenzkontrollen und Einreisebeschränkungen](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/kurzmeldungen/DE/2020/03/corona-ein-und-ausreise.html) Personen, die nicht die deutsche Staatsangehörigkeit haben, dürfen unter folgenden Bedingungen einreisen: Zur Heimreise nach Deutschland zum gewöhnlichen Aufenthaltsort bzw. Wohnsitz.

Comment: @averell Translated: Persons who are not of German nationality may enter under the following conditions: To travel home to Germany to their usual place of residence or domicile.

Comment: @MarkJohnson - that seems correct, although the is technically only about land borders - the section about air/sea below (which is probably what the English version is translated from) only speaks about "zum Zwecke der Durchreise" (for _transit_). But yes, even that section implies that residents will be allowed.

Comment: @averell The original quote for air/sea in my answer also states : peaple with residence title or longer-term visa.

Answer (score 6):

Do you already have a residence arranged in Germany, as in apartment already located and contract signed? If not, you might have a hard time being let in, and even if you are allowed in, might have practical problems getting housing, both long-term and short-term, as hotels are not supposed to rent rooms to tourists right now, foreign or domestic.

Another thing to consider: you have not registered with the town you are going to live in ("Anmeldung" is separate from residence permit, and only possible once you have an address) so Germany does not have a place that it considers your habitual residence yet. As you are not coming *back* to something, your entry is likely to be considered non-essential, unless you're coming over here to work on something related to the pandemic.

On a daily life level, you're not going to be able to buy anything other than groceries, because pretty much anything that's not a grocery store, drugstore or pharmacy is closed, and there's no scheduled re-opening date. You're not going to go to classes or lectures, you're not going to visit any museums or historical sites and you're not going to see any performances - all of those things are closed through at least the end of the scheduled Easter holidays (19 April). Restaurants are delivery/carry-out only.

We've been spared Italy-level suffering so far, but I would seriously not move here right now. Stay in Canada until things have calmed down a bit.

Comment: Anmeldung might not even be possible right now.  At least where I live, the Meldebehörde is closed.

Comment: You're right! My town, one of the largest in Bavaria, closed city offices to the public on 18 March, has no planned opening date and is not accepting appointments: https://services.fuerth.de/

Germany is CLOSED.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a company you planned on working for, you might ask them if remote working is okay/posbible. Basically all jobs that can be done remote are doing this right now.